# SQL query - how to get 2 or more rows with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. One is customer table with columns: cid, name, state. 
Another table is Purchase table with columns: pid, cid, booktitle, price.

CUSTOMER:

```
CID    NAME    STATE
1      Peng    NY
2      Li      IL
3      Chan    NY
```

PURCHASE:

```
PID CID BOOKTITLE PRICE
10  1   ABC       20 
11  3   XYZ       15 
12  1   MNOP      12
```

OUTPUT:

```
STATE CID  NAME 
NY    1    Peng
IL    null null
```

I need to output the cid and name of customers in each state who have the highest purchases(maximum orders). I am able to output the cid, name, state and number of purchases for each customer but not get it for each state as I cannot use more columns while using group by function:

```
select c.cid, c.name, c.state, d.orders 
from customer c
left join (select cid, count(pid) as orders 
           from purchase
           group by cid) d
on c.cid = d.cid;
```

Can anyone suggest how should I proceed?

Comment: You are talking about "maximum orders" but in the ORDERS table you only have a PRICE column. Do you mean "maximum price"? Also, what do you want returned if in a state there are two or more customers tied for the highest price? Return both (all) of them? Or just one of them, at random?

Comment: No. Not price. I mean maximum number of orders placed. Meaning, maximum purchases done by a customer.

Comment: For the second part in case of tie, random customer or both(all) of them works. Any of the output is acceptable. Thanks

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Based on your wording above, **you need** cid and customer name grouped by state, but **you already have** cid, customer name, state, and number of orders. Please be more specific with your problem and provide an example table of your expected output.

Comment: @EdwardRusu Sorry, I am new to this. I do not have number of orders. I only have a table called purchase that records the single orders placed by various customers. I had already given the output table above. maybe you didn't see it. please tell me what else should I clarify on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cnt as (
select c.state, c.name, c.cid, count(p.cid) orders from customer c  
left outer join purchase p on p.cid = c.cid
group by c.state, c.name, c.cid )
select state, 
case when orders=0 then null else cid end cid, 
case when orders=0 then null else name end name 
from (select state, name, cid, orders, 
      row_number() over (partition by state order by orders desc) rn
      from cnt)
order by name, state;
```

results:

```
STATE             CID NAME
---------- ---------- ----------
NY                  1 Peng
IL
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I didn't realize I could solve this with analytical functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine window functions with aggregation functions:

```
select cp.*
from (select c.cid, c.name, c.state, count(p.cid) as orders,
             row_number() over (partition by c.state order by count(p.cid) desc) as seqnum
      from customer c left join
           purchase p
           on c.cid = p.cid
      group by c.cid, c.name, c.state
     ) cp
where seqnum = 1;
```

The value you are looking for is called the `mode`.  If you want all modes for a given state, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: the join should be on c.cid = p.cid; regardless, this doesn't give IL as part of the result.

Comment: @gregory . . . I think that just needs a `left join` rather than `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    orders AS
    (   -- enumerate the values by buckets of state 
        -- ordered by num_orders per state
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY num_orders DESC) rn
            , state
            , cid
            , num_orders
        FROM
        (   -- calculate counts by state and customer id
            SELECT
                c.state
                , p.cid
                , COUNT(p.pid) as num_orders
            FROM        purchase p
            INNER JOIN  customer c ON p.cid = c.cid
            GROUP BY    
                c.state
                , p.cid
        )

    )
-- return desired values
SELECT
    c.state
    , c.cid
    c.name
FROM        customer    c
LEFT JOIN   orders      o 
ON 
    c.cid = o.cid 
    AND c.state = o.state
    AND rn = 1
```